# sharing menu between main site and sub site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, razor

I have a site "mysite.com" that is an asp.net MVC 5.2 application. To maintain separation of concerns I have implemented "blog.mysite.com" as a virtual application. It is the very cool [MiniBlog by Mads Kristenson](https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog); a Razor Web Pages application in a virtual directory.

Correction: I'm actually employing an IIS virtual folder/application using "blog". So URL is "mysite.com/blog" as opposed to a sub-domain scenario using "blog.mysite.com".

I want to reuse/embed my html header section from the root site, (the menu from "mysite.com", which is uses bootstrap 3 navbar), into the 
blog web site at "blog.mysite.com". Is this possible? Is there a relatively clean or slick way of doing this sort of thing? I'm trying to avoid having to maintain a copy of my root menu system in the virtual app.

The main site uses a partial view in the _Layout.cshtml to render the the menu/navbar, (html header section) and uses both server and client-side dynamics.

There is an administration menu that is only sent to the browser if the user is authenticated. This is controlled server-side, in the partial view, by checking Request.IsAuthenticated.

Also, on the client-side, there are triggers that dynamically show/hide portions of the menu. I have a "Demo" sub-menu that can be toggled. The same button controls the visibility of a viewport size monitor to help demonstrate responsive design. The state of this "demo mode" is all controlled by a simple cookie via jquery.cookie.js.

Comment: I have done what you suggest by extending the MvcSiteMapProvider and putting it all in a database including the roles data. Probably a lot more than you want to do. Curious if anybody else has a better suggestion.

Comment: Since you should be authorising an action call when it's made rather than simply relying on whether or not a user can see it, you could dump the Request.IsAuthenticated method as means of dynamic menu generation and just go by a parameter in the querystring calling the partial. You can set that param in the caller by using Request.IsAuthenticated if it suits but  either way the menu itself is typically not sensitive rather just a means of producing a better Ux. If you did that and then made your calls via ajax then you only have a content replacement scenario on your hands aka UpdatePanel.

Comment: Alternatively you could wrap the menu generator in an htmlhelper, bundle that into an assembly and then ref from each project.

Comment: Ooop! Actually misstated my question a little. In IIS the virtual application is not associated with a sub domain. So my blog url is like "mysite.com/blog" and not "blog.mysite.com". It's simply set up as a virtual directory/application. I don't know how much changes things.

Comment: rism, thx. I'll start by tinkering with the AJAX UpdatePanel. I agree that the my use of the Request.IsAuthenticated in the view is a hindrance; it's an admin menu that is unrelated to the blog. It won't matter if it disappears while in the blog application.

Comment: Is there some way to return the menu as a partial view...as AJAX ?

Comment: Follow up: reuse of menu was simple using basic techniques explained here:
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc

Client-side dynamics: the MiniBlog is running in a virtual folder so it was easy to share the same cookie for tracking "demo mode" state.

Server-side dynamics: Seemingly no "relatively clean or slick way" to handle the portions of the menu that should only be visible to authenticated users. Trey Gramann probably has it right; it requires a custom, server-side data store, accessible to both main app. and sub/virt. app. THX. ALL!